# How to call out javascript function which is assigned to a variable?

Tags: javascript

```
function test1 (){
    //do something
}
```

To call out the function above, i just need to write `test1();`

```
var check_day = function($select_d){
    //do something
};
```

How can I call out the function which is assigned to a variable?

Comment: Refer this link for other options http://devlicio.us/blogs/sergio_pereira/archive/2009/02/09/javascript-5-ways-to-call-a-function.aspx

Comment: WOW. There are many ways that i never seen before. Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The same way–call a function using parens `()`:

```
check_day(the_parameter);
```